# Application defined or object-defined error ('1004')

Tags: excel, vba

So I'm trying to create a databar for a set of specific cells (i.e. cells next to a percentage format).
So what I tried to do is, create a string of range that only have specific cells (Ex. A1, B1, D4, H7) and saved this string into count_n.
But when I input this range into the Sheet(4).Range(count_n).Select I'm getting this error- "Application defined or object-defined error ('1004')"

Can you guys help me out where I'm going wrong? This is however working if I manually save the range in a string and input the string in Sheet(4).Range().Select.

```
Sub ConditionalFormat()
    Dim rngCell As Range
    Dim count_n As String
    Dim count_p As String
    Dim rng As Range
    
    Set rng = Range("A1:AG200")
    
    For Each rngCell In rng
        If Right((Sheets(4).Cells(rngCell.Row, rngCell.Column).NumberFormat), 1) = "%" Then
            count_n = count_n & "," & Sheets(4).Cells(rngCell.Row, rngCell.Column - 1).Address(0, 0)
            
        End If
    Next rngCell
    
    count_n = Trim(Mid(count_n, 2, Len(count_n)))

    
    MsgBox (count_n)
    
    
    Sheets(4).Select
    Sheets(4).Range(count_n).Select
    Sheets(4).Range(count_n).Activate
    

    Selection.FormatConditions.AddDatabar
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.count).ShowValue = True
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1)
        .MinPoint.Modify newtype:=xlConditionValueAutomaticMin
        .MaxPoint.Modify newtype:=xlConditionValueAutomaticMax
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).BarColor
        .Color = 8700771
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).BarFillType = xlDataBarFillGradient
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).Direction = xlContext
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).NegativeBarFormat.ColorType = xlDataBarColor
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).BarBorder.Type = xlDataBarBorderSolid
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).NegativeBarFormat.BorderColorType = _
        xlDataBarColor
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).BarBorder.Color
        .Color = 8700771
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).AxisPosition = xlDataBarAxisAutomatic
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).AxisColor
        .Color = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).NegativeBarFormat.Color
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).NegativeBarFormat.BorderColor
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Does it work if you type that as a string (hard-code it) into the call to `Range`? I doubt it will.

Comment: Yup. It doesn't

Comment: If you can't do it with the same string hard-coded, then you can't do it in code that way either.

Comment: Got it. But it works when I hard code a small string like "A1,D4,E4,A2". Any idea why?

Comment: There's a 255-character limit to the address passed to `Range`. You probably need `Union`.